# Possible to change radius of section in Vega Lite arc (pie chart) plot on click?

Tags: vega-lite

I've been using Vega Lite to design some interactive visualizations, and I’m trying to figure out if I either understand something about how signals and params work improperly, or if the `radius` field of an arc chart is uniquely un-drivable with params/signals. The goal is to add some interactivity to a pie chart where a selected section "grows" its radius slightly, to emphasize that it is selected:

[image: Screenshot of desired end form of Vega Lite plot]

Adapting one of the vega-lite arc plot examples, I wanted to make the radius change dimensions on click. If I make a param for selection and use that in an opacity encoding, I can change the color opacity on click; but if I put in *radius*, no dice. Is this by intent, a bug, or a misunderstanding of what properties can take a condition?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Pie Chart with percentage_tooltip",
  "data": {
    "values": [ {"category": 1, "value": 4}, {"category": 2, "value": 6}, {"category": 3, "value": 10}, {"category": 4, "value": 3}, {"category": 5, "value": 7}, {"category": 6, "value": 8}]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "select", "select": "point"}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "arc", "tooltip": true},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "normalize"},
    "fillOpacity": {
      "condition": {
        "param": "select",
        "value": 1
      },
      "value": 0.5
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "category", "type": "nominal"
    },
    "radius": {
      "condition": {
        "param": "select",
        "value": 100
      },
      "value": 80
    }
  }
}
```

I’ve also tried using an expression within the mark object,

```
"radius": { "expr": "select === 'point' ? 100 : 80" }
```

and also computing a derived value and trying to bind the radius to that

```
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "select === 'point' ? 80 : 100", "as": "scaledRadius"}
  ],
```

but none of these approaches seem to achieve the look I'm trying to go for, where the selected section is displayed with a larger radius. Could anybody point me to where my thinking is going wrong, with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this spec. I have added quite a few properties with conditional expressions for you to play with.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Pie Chart with percentage_tooltip",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "params": [
    {"name": "select", "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["category"]}}
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "arc",
    "tooltip": true,
    "stroke": "white",
    "strokeWidth": 0.5,
    "padAngle": {"expr": "select.category == datum.category ? 0.05 : 0"},
    "radius": {"expr": "select.category == datum.category ? 106: 100"},
    "radius2": {"expr": "select.category == datum.category ? 3: 0"},
    "cornerRadius": {"expr": "select.category == datum.category ? 3: 0"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "order": {"field": "value", "sort": "ascending"},
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "fillOpacity": {"condition": {"param": "select", "value": 1}, "value": 0.6},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Here is a slightly different approach if you want all other pie slices to shrink :)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Pie Chart with percentage_tooltip",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "width": 300,
  "height": 300,
  "params": [
    {"name": "select", "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["category"]}}
  ],
  "mark": {

    "type": "arc",
    "tooltip": true,
    "stroke": "white",
    "strokeWidth": 0.5,
    "radius": {"expr": "select.category == null ? 130: select.category == datum.category ? 130: 70"},
  },
  "encoding": {
    "order": {"field": "value", "sort": "ascending"},
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "fillOpacity": {"condition": {"param": "select", "value": 1}, "value": 0.4},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

One final option to apply a square root calc so all pie slices have a relative radius according to their value.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Pie Chart with percentage_tooltip",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8},
      {"category": 7, "value": 30}
    ]
  },
  "width": 300,
  "height": 300,
  "params": [
    {"name": "select", "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["category"]}}
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "arc",
    "tooltip": true,
    "stroke": "white",
    "strokeWidth": 0.5,
    "radius": {"expr": "select.category != null ? sqrt(datum.value)*30 : 130"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "order": {"field": "value", "sort": "ascending"},
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "fillOpacity": {"condition": {"param": "select", "value": 1}, "value": 0.4},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Comment: That does it — using the

`{"name": "select", "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["category"]}}`

param allows the

`"radius": {"expr": "select.category == datum.category ? 106: 100"},`

in your example to work where my the prior `select` param without fields did not. May I ask if you have any more detailed information about why this works when the other solutions we attempted did not?

In any event, thank you!

Comment: If we don't set the "fields" then the param just provides the "_vgsid_". We can still use this to extract the "Set" value but it is more complex. Glad I could help.